# Access properties file in an executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

My goal is to create an executable jar from Eclipse. I have an Eclipse project which runs fine with the structure below.

**My Eclipse project**

```
src/main/java
-com.main
      ->MyClass

src/main/resources
 ->MyProps.properties
```

`MyClass` is able to access `MyProps.properties` file successfully.

After I export the Eclipse project and create a runnable jar then my jar structure is like below.

**MyJar.jar**

```
-com.main
  ->MyClass

-resources
 ->MyProps.properties
```

When I run the jar file it fails to access the properties file throwing a `NullPointerExeception`.

**My code**

```
InputStream input = MyClass.class.getClassLoader()
                           .getResourceAsStream("resources/MyProps.properties");
```

When I export my project as an executable jar file, I cannot access `MyProps.properties` anymore.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Show us your code that accesses the properties file.

Comment: please add the code you tried. Its looks like a `maven` project and you try to access this file as a resource .

Comment: `InputStream file = MyClass.getResourceAsStream("/resources/MyProps.properties")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like below to read a properties file on the Class Path:

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MyProps.properties")
```

Answer (score 0):

In onder to load a file from a jar. You have to use `Class.getResource()` or `Class.getResourceAsStream()`.

```
URL properties = ConfigLoaderTest.class.getResource("/resources/MyProps.properties");
```

This will load the file from your classpath, this means it will also look inside the jars on your classpath (the executable jar is on your classpath automatically). **The first '/' indicates to look from the root of the jars on your classpath, you have omitted this in your code.**

The URL you can then read like any URL (it will return null if none is found). For instant by using `properties.openStream()`.

Note that it seems you are using the default maven structure `src/main/resources`, however you have `src/main` on your eclipse buildpath, so in your jar you get the `resources` directory. Normal for maven projects is to have `src/main/resources` on your buildpath. Which would place your properties file in the root of your jar.

Comment: It should be accessed within jar

Comment: This will also look in the contents of your jar, I have added this to the answer.

Comment: As you have added your code, I have highlighted the difference with your code in my post.